# N step fft in D language

Tags: signal-processing, fft, d

I am using fft function from std.numeric

```
Complex!double[] resultfft = fft(timeDomainAmplitudeVal);
```

The parameter timeDomainAmplitudeVal is audio amplitude data. Sample rate 44100 hz and there is 131072(2^16) samples

I am seeing that resultfft has the same size as timeDomainAmplitudeVal(131072) which does not fits my project(also makes no sense) . I need to be able to divide FFT to N equally spaced frequencies. And I need this N to be defined by me .

Is there anyway to implement this with std.numeric.fft or can you have any advices for fft library?

Ps: I will be glad to hear if some DSP libraries exist also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just how Fourier transforms work in the practical number-crunching world.  Give S samples of signal, get S amplitudes.  (Ignoring issues with complex numbers and symmetries.)

If you want N amplitudes, you'll have to interpolate the S-points amplitudes you get from FFT.   Your biggest decision is to choose between linear, cubic, truncated sinc, etc.

Altnernative: resample the original audio signal to have your desired N samples in the same overall time interval.  Then FFT it.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at pfft, a fast FFT written in D.

http://jerro.github.io/pfft/doc/pfft.pfft.html

or numpy & Pyd

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html

http://pyd.dsource.org/

HTH

Comment: Thanks , I will check it out. I am more intreseted with first one because it is purely written in D not a wrapper. I am learining D for its advantages I don't think using a wrapper, in where you need performance most, is good.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely normal that the FFT gives the same data length.

Here some C++ code to perform windows FFT analysis with overlap and optional "zero-phase" ordering. http://pastebin.com/4YKgbed1

---

**What do FFT coefficients mean?**

**Question:** "OK so I've done the FFT and I'm said I can recover the original signal. Now, what *are* these coefficients."

**Answer:** "You can think of coefficient i as representing the phase and amplitude of frequencies from SR*i/(2*N) to SR*(i+1)/(2*N). This is a helpful metaphor. But a more accurate view is that coefficient i is the contribution of a sine of frequency SR*i/(2*N) in a reconstruction of the original input chunk."